# How to close dialog by self with vuejs2?

Tags: vuejs2

I am writing a dialog component, i don't know how to close dialog by self.

```
<template>
  <div class="dialog" v-show="visible">
    ...
    <button @click="close">Close</button>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  {
    props: {visible: {type: Boolean, default: false}},
    methods: {
      close () {
        // this.visible = false //It will get vue warn
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

So, how to close the dialog in my component, i can't update `visible` prop, i will get a error.

```
Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "visible"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Props are [one way data flow](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#One-Way-Data-Flow)

You should not mutate the prop received from a parent component in the child component

So emit an [custom event](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Custom-Events) to mutate the prop in parent component itself

```
<template>
  <div class="dialog" v-show="visible">
    ...
    <button @click="close">Close</button>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  {
    props: {visible: {type: Boolean, default: false}},
    methods: {
      close () {
        // this.visible = false //It will get vue warn
        this.$emit('close-dialog')
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

**parent component**

```
<template>
    <div>
    <my-dialozg @close-dialog="visible = false" :visible="visible"><my-dialog>
    </div>
</template>
```

Setup an event listener `close-dialog` on the dialog component and set the data property `visible` that you pass as a prop to `false`. You can do this inline as shown above or extract it into a method also

Comment: Thanks, `.sync` is what i want.

Answer (score 1):

In vuejs, child component can not modify the parents property directly.

You can use events/event listeners for that. But since your example is simple you don't need an event for that.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/samayo/943bx5px/28/

Instead, you can pass the prop visible to your component as `:visisble="visible"` and watch the state change as:

```
watch: {
  visible (val) {
    if(!val) {
        // close
    }else{
        open
    }
  }
}
```

Now, if `visisble` is toggled to false from the parent, your modal will not be visible.